# Properties of a matroid relaxation

Tags: reference-request, matroids

Consider a matroid $M$ on a ground set $E$ with a subset $X \subseteq E$ such that $X$ is both a circuit and a hyperplane of $M$. If $\mathcal B(M)$ is the set of bases of $M$, then we can form a new matroid by the so-called *relaxation technique*, that is, a new matroid with set of bases $\mathcal B(M) \cup \{X\}$.

**Question**: 
Is there an extensive paper that deals with the properties of these matroid relaxations?

Comment: Did you check out Oxley's book?

Comment: Yes. There is not enough information about matroid relaxations.

Answer (score 1):

These are often called circuit-hyperplane relaxations. A relatively recent paper using it is *Matroid fragility and relaxations of circuit hyperplanes*, where the authors, Jim Geelen and Florian Hoersch, talk about its role with respect to $\mathbb{F}$-representability and Rota's conjecture.

Comment: Thank you! +1 I have to work my way through the paper ;-)